# Native javascript way to get user's IP address

Tags: javascript, network-programming

It seems impossible to get your IP address with pure javascript without recurring to external services or server side code.

My question is: why didn't the language implement this feature natively? After all, the browser should know "its" IP address.

Comment: The browser knows it's IP address, sure.  Why do *you* need it?  You can't get it from the browser for security reasons.

Comment: Actually, you *can* get the user's IP address with JavaScript.  WebRTC has a security flaw (read: feature) that can get both your external and *internal* IPs.  Have a gander at https://ipleak.net/, it uses code based off https://github.com/diafygi/webrtc-ips

Comment: My question was simpler: why doesn't native Javascript have a "getMyIP()" function?

Comment: I'd say it's just for security/privacy.  Though, with the code from https://github.com/diafygi/webrtc-ips, JavaScript basically *does* have a `getMyIP()` function.

Answer (score 7):

You actually *can* the user's IP address using vanilla JavaScript.  WebRTC has a security flaw (read: feature) that lets get both the user's external and even *internal* (LAN) IP addresses.

Have a look at this GitHub project: https://github.com/diafygi/webrtc-ips

```
//get the IP addresses associated with an account
function getIPs(callback){
    var ip_dups = {};

    //compatibility for firefox and chrome
    var RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection
        || window.mozRTCPeerConnection
        || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
    var useWebKit = !!window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;

    //bypass naive webrtc blocking using an iframe
    if(!RTCPeerConnection){
        //NOTE: you need to have an iframe in the page right above the script tag
        //
        //<iframe id="iframe" sandbox="allow-same-origin" style="display: none"></iframe>
        //<script>...getIPs called in here...
        //
        var win = iframe.contentWindow;
        RTCPeerConnection = win.RTCPeerConnection
            || win.mozRTCPeerConnection
            || win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
        useWebKit = !!win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
    }

    //minimal requirements for data connection
    var mediaConstraints = {
        optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]
    };

    var servers = {iceServers: [{urls: "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com"}]};

    //construct a new RTCPeerConnection
    var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers, mediaConstraints);

    function handleCandidate(candidate){
        //match just the IP address
        var ip_regex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/
        var ip_addr = ip_regex.exec(candidate)[1];

        //remove duplicates
        if(ip_dups[ip_addr] === undefined)
            callback(ip_addr);

        ip_dups[ip_addr] = true;
    }

    //listen for candidate events
    pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){

        //skip non-candidate events
        if(ice.candidate)
            handleCandidate(ice.candidate.candidate);
    };

    //create a bogus data channel
    pc.createDataChannel("");

    //create an offer sdp
    pc.createOffer(function(result){

        //trigger the stun server request
        pc.setLocalDescription(result, function(){}, function(){});

    }, function(){});

    //wait for a while to let everything done
    setTimeout(function(){
        //read candidate info from local description
        var lines = pc.localDescription.sdp.split('\n');

        lines.forEach(function(line){
            if(line.indexOf('a=candidate:') === 0)
                handleCandidate(line);
        });
    }, 1000);
}

//Test: Print the IP addresses into the console
getIPs(function(ip){console.log(ip);});
```

Check out the demo: https://diafygi.github.io/webrtc-ips/

Comment: That's oddly terrifying.

Comment: @ScottKaye: What's worse is (according to a Mozilla bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=959893), it's by design.  See: http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-rtcweb-security-arch-07#section-5.4

Comment: It's not giving public ip.

Comment: As of 2022, this doesn't work in any browser I've tried (Chrome, Firefox, Edge).